# Objects are not valid as a React child (object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've created this screen that gets an object. But get this error when I try to render it:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I know the reason that I'm getting the object `{_U, _V, _W, _X}` is because it's not got the history data yet, but I don't understand why it's not waiting to render.

Below are the classes that load the screen:

**HistoryScreen.js**

```
...

class HistoryPopulator extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    async getHistory(){ // gets object used to create cards
        const checkIns = new CheckInUtil()

        const history = await checkIns.getCheckInHistory(); // should return object of history data

        return (history.data.checkInsByUser ? history.data.checkInsByUser : false) ; // if no data found returns false
    }

    Header(props) {
        return (
            <View {...props}>
                <Text category="h4"><PinIcon/> {props}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    async render() {
        const history = await this.getHistory();

        let historyCards = null;

        if (history) { // if history found
            history.reverse(); // Reverse order of data

            for (checkIn of history) {
                const newCheckIn = (
                    <Card style={styles.historyCard} header={this.Header(checkIn.beacon.venue.venueName)}>
                        <Text category='h6'>Date: {new Date(checkIn.dateIn).toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.historyCardTime} category='h5'>Checked-In: new
                            Date(checkIn.dateIn).toLocaleTimeString()</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.historyCardTime} category='h5'>Checked-Out: new
                            Date(checkIn.dateOut).toLocaleTimeString()</Text>
                        <Text>No Current Positive Exposure</Text>
                    </Card>
                );
                historyCards = historyCards + newCheckIn;
            }
        } else { // if nothing found return simple card
            historyCards = (
                <Card style={styles.historyCard}>
                    <Text category='h6'>No Previous Check Ins Found.</Text>
                </Card>
            );
        }

        return historyCards;


    }
}


class HistoryScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.navigation = props.navigation
    };

    navigateBack() {
        this.navigation.goBack();
    };

    BackAction() {
        return <TopNavigationAction icon={BackIcon} onPress={this.navigation.goBack()}/>
    };

    Header(props) {
        return (
            <View {...props}>
                <Text category="h4"><PinIcon/> The One Eyed Dog</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.navContainer}>
                <TopNavigation
                    accessoryLeft={this.BackAction}
                    title='Check-in History'
                />
                <ScrollView style={styles.containerWNav}>
                    <HistoryPopulator />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }

}

export default HistoryScreen;
```

Additionally, I get an error saying `this.navigation` is undefined. Am I right in assuming this is cause by the above error as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you should change:

1. You can't concatenate jsx elements with this syntax `historyCards = historyCards + newCheckIn;`. Replace the `for`..loop for a `map`.
2. You should always separate the fetching data from the part of displaying it. I recommend you to store the history data in the component state, then call getHistory in `componentDidMount`.
3. The `render` function should not be async. That is the main reason of the error you are getting.

```
 constructor (props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
       history: null
    };
  }

 async componentDidMount () {
   const data = await getHistory(); 
   this.setState({history: data});
 }

 render () {
    ...
    historyCards = this.state.history.map((checkIn) => (
                        <Card style={styles.historyCard} header={this.Header(checkIn.beacon.venue.venueName)}>
                            <Text category='h6'>Date: {new Date(checkIn.dateIn).toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.historyCardTime} category='h5'>Checked-In: new
                                Date(checkIn.dateIn).toLocaleTimeString()</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.historyCardTime} category='h5'>Checked-Out: new
                                Date(checkIn.dateOut).toLocaleTimeString()</Text>
                            <Text>No Current Positive Exposure</Text>
                        </Card>
                    )
                );

 ...

 return historyCards;

 }
```

Comment: I tried with the updated code, but I still get the objects are not valid error.

Comment: Are you sure that history is an array, Is this history.data.checkInsByUser an array?

Comment: Yes it returns an array of objects. I'm using GraphQL to get the data

Comment: You need to change other things, like render the data outside of the render function, render function shouldn't be async. I will edit my answer

Comment: It's #3 that solves my case.

Answer (score 0):

@lissettdm 's answer solved the main error of:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

But didn't fix the navigation error I also mentioned. To fix this I replaced the functions:

```
    navigateBack() {
        this.navigation.goBack();
    };

    BackAction() {
        return <TopNavigationAction icon={BackIcon} onPress={this.navigation.goBack()}/>
    };
```

in the HistoryScreen class, with these functions:

```
    navigateBack = () => {
        this.navigation.goBack();
    };

    BackAction = () => (
        <TopNavigationAction icon={BackIcon} onPress={this.navigateBack}/>
    );
```

Which seems to fix the error:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.navigateBack')
```